# Numpy: classify 2D array raster based on combinations of two 2D array rasters

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, raster

I have two 2D numpy arrays representing raster images where classes `1, 2, 3` exist.

I need to obtain all possible combinations of these two arrays (should be `3 × 3 = 9` in this case) and create a new 2D array that is classified to `1-8` based on which combination exists at the spot.

There are also `np.nan` values as it is natural for rasters (must be MxN rectangle) but there is never a combination of `np.nan` and a valid category.

Example how I imagine that with small sample arrays:

Input arrays:

```
a = np.array([
    [1,2,3],
    [3,1,1]
])

b = np.array([
    [1,2,1],
    [3,3,3]
])
```

Possible combinations (imagine above arrays are much bigger and these combinations probably all occur):

```
possible_combinations = [
    (1,1), # class 1
    (2,1), # class 2
    (3,1), # class 3 
    (1,2), # class 4
    (1,3), # class 5
    (2,2), # class 6
    (2,3), # class 7
    (3,2), # class 8
    (3,3)  # class 9
]
```

Newly classified array:

```
>>> array(
       [[1, 6, 3],
        [9, 5, 5]]
    )
```

### Edit

@Andrej Kesely's answer principally got it. One issue, I forgot to mention explicitly, arises when two `nan` values meet in the pair/pixel vector. This is an undesired class (and a combination as it does not make sense since `np.nan != np.nan`). To ditch these pairs we just need to modify the last step of the solution:

```
x = np.array(
    [[np.nan if all(np.isnan(pixel) for pixel in y) else possibl_combinations[tuple(y)] for y in x] for x in np.dstack((imgs[0], imgs[1]))]
)
```

Now it already becomes a pretty awful one-liner but still works.

Comment: Is looping too slow?  It seems like just generating permutations and looping over the indices would be a really simple way to do this unless you are expecting large inputs

Comment: I do expect large inputs, that's why looping actually didn't come to my mind at first. But that would definitely be the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.dstack` to "zip" the two matrices.

```py
# to speed up, convert possible_combinations to dict:
possible_combinations = {c: i for i, c in enumerate(possible_combinations, 1)}

x = np.array(
    [[possible_combinations[tuple(y)] for y in x] for x in np.dstack((a, b))]
)
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
[[1 6 3]
 [9 5 5]]
```

Comment: Thanks! Because I expected larger inputs I tried to fend off converting back to non-numpy structures. One issue, I forgot to mention, arises when two nan values meet each other in the pair. I've elaborated on your solution in my edit.